# CarrierWave uploader cannot find model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, carrierwave

I have the following structure: An Fsvideo object belongs to a User, and the foreign key relationship is established.  The video object is uploaded to an Amazon S3 bucket.  My Fsvideo model below:

```
class Fsvideo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user, :video
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :video, MyVideoUploader
```

The uploader below:

```
class MyVideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :fog
  def store_dir
    "videos/#{model.user.id.to_s.underscore}"
  end
end
```

The problem lies in that whenever the store_dir method is called, a NoMethodError(undefined method 'user for nil:NilClass) is thrown.  The odd part is that, when I change the store_dire method to return the following string:

```
"videos/#{model.class}"
```

It works fine, and the file is uploaded to the S3 storage space without error.  Going into rails console and checking that the video has been mounted successfully, I see that

```
Fsvideo.find(18).video.model.user.id
```

Will return the exact property that I'm looking for.

My question is essentially, why am I able to access this property through the console, but not through my uploader class?

Answer (score 0):

Try "videos/#{model.user_id.to_s.underscore}" The video record should have the user_id as its property.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I still receive a NoMethodError (undefined method 'user_id' for nil:NilClass).  I believe the problem may be in the model not being accessed (explaining the NilClass).